# How to check logs generated through logrus, to get a count of the no. of errors and warnings

Tags: go, logging

I wanted to a way through which we could keep the count of no. of errors and warnings that have occurred in logrus logs.

I want to use a struct to keep count of the errors and warnings,

```
    type ErrorsAndWarnings struct{
        Errors int
        Warnings int
    }
```

Comment: If there is any way by which I can get a count of errors and warnings through logs generated by logrus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hooks in logrus. Hook will be called each time an log will be called for a level.

```
// You can make Errors and Warnings as atomic integers or probably 
// use locks to make it thread safe
type ErrorsAndWarnings struct{
        Errors int
        Warnings int
}

var (
    levels = []logrus.Level{logrus.WarnLevel, logrus.ErrorLevel}
)

func (h *ErrorsAndWarnings) Levels() []logrus.Level {
    return levels
}

func (h *ErrorsAndWarnings) Fire(entry *logrus.Entry) error {
    if entry.Level == logrus.ErrorLevel{
      h.Errors++
    }else if entry.Level == logrus.WarnLevel{
       h.Warnings++
    }
    return nil
}
```